# after remove tr from table with javascript when submit sends all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hve a table in a html page, with a function it is possible to remove the selected row, but when i press the submit button all rows are submitted. if i see the  source code i can see the html with all rows. this is the function i am using.

**EDIT**
this is how the table look like.

[image: table with the option to delete rows]

this is the initialization code for the button to bind it with the function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
});
```

this is the function that deletes the row.

```
function Delete(){
        var rowCount = $('#datallesNota tr').length;
        console.log('FILAS EN LA TABLA: ' + rowCount );

        console.log('ELIMINAR FILA: ');

        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        par.remove();
        console.log('SE REMOVIO LA FILA: ' );
    };
```

this is part of the table where the function is called.

```
<tr id="1">
<td><button class="btnDelete"><img alt="QUITAR" src="/resources/img/16x16/delete.png"> </button>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `Delete()` in the bind function?

Comment: How do you select the row?

Comment: I believe you'll have to do define the Delete variable like this `var Delete = function Delete(){//your function code};` so you can call it the way you do

Comment: Maybe i was not clear about the problem, this code deletes the row of the table, the user is able to delete as many rows as desired, the problem is that when the user submits the form, all rows, even the deleted rows are submitted to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of removing a tr from table.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4d78m4y9/)

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="1">
        <td>My Conten1</td>

    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>My Conten2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>My Conten3</td>
    </tr>
    <table>
        <button class="btnDelete">Click Me</button> 

$(".btnDelete").on("click", function(){
    var rowId = 2;
    deleteRow(rowId);
});

function deleteRow(rowId){
  var selectedRow = $("#myTable tr[id="+rowId+"]");
    $(selectedRow).remove();
}
```

Comment: It help me, tank you, besides checking the code i found some wrong logic. after that i worked fine.